# Javascript to get data but IE cannot show data apporiately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I not sure the reason or how to explain it clearly, but my web UI is all great in firefox and crome.

I use httprequest to get data and show information in UI dynamically, but only IE cannot shows data correctly.

I use a block to change the innerHTML depends on the data returned, and the UI are `<select>` and `<ul><li>`.
My block is like that:

```
<ul id="roomlist" class="room_menu">
    <li id="allroom" class="txtunderline" style="text-align: right;">All Room</li>
</ul>
```

There is an original li called 'allroom', after get data from server, the block 'roomlist' will change the innerHTML.

In function `onreadystatechange`, I get some data and put into array, then change roomlist like:

first, add the last li called 'createroom'

```
var createRoom="<li id=\"createroom\" class=\"txtunderline\"><div style=\"text-align: right;\">"+"CreateRooms"+"</div></li>";
$("#allroom").after(createRoom);
```

then add each li of rooms, but IE(I tried IE8, IE10) just show the allroom and createroom, others not showned. I guess maybe that is because other `<li>` is customized with image like:

```
var oldRoom="<li id=\"room"+index+"\">";
oldRoom+="<table style=\"width: 100%; position: relative; top: -2px; left: -2px;\"><tr><td><img width=\"28px\" height=\"28px\" src=\"images/location/" + locatImg[index] + "\" /></td><td align=\"right\">" + locatInfo[index]+"</td></tr></table></li>";
$("#createroom").before(oldRoom);
```

The result may like that in crome or firefox:
[image]

but in IE:
[image]

If I look the DOM in google will be:

[image]

And I use `<select>` to show the data is empty, too.

I have debugged by `alert` data, and `alert` function is ok( can use javascript), but when I alert the data I get, the alert not triggered. It let me guess there may something wrong so the alert cannot pop up until the bug be solved.( but the status bar of IE not show any wrong messages)

I use jQuery, the version is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I heard that jQuery not compatible since version 2.0 released, but my version seem not 2.0 version?

And the same kind list(`<ul><li>` pairs) in other pages are shown well, and there is no image added to the list.

I beat my brains out and hope someone can help me to find out the real problems, any help appreciate!

Edit: Sorry, I try to simplify the list just display text like:

```
var oldRoom="<li id=\"room"+index+"\">" + locatInfo[index] + "</li>";
$("#createroom").before(oldRoom);
```

And in IE it still the same:

[image]

while in crome the structure is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reengineer your code to use less inline CSS, and take the tables out. Your approach is very scattered, and you could be running into style conflicts or other issues. For example that `position` style could be the source of your problem, but it's difficult to know because your markup isn't very semantic.

And it should be noted you're [appearing to use tables incorrectly](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm), however it could be that you've just left out a lot of the extra room information that would make this a tabular list of information.

In the case that you are ONLY displaying your room with an icon, you can simply make a series of CSS classes with the background images you want, and then assign the correct class to the `<li>`.

For example your CSS could include:

```
ul#roomList, ul#roomList li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul#roomList li {
  width: 10em;
  height: 28px;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
}

ul#roomList li.roomType1 {
  background-image: url('/images/room1.png');
}

ul#roomList li.roomType2 {
  background-image: url('/images/room3.png');
}

ul#roomList li.roomType3 {
  background-image: url('/images/room3.png');
}
```

And in your HTML you would simply use:

```
<ul id="roomList">
  <li class="roomType3">Some text for room 3</li>
  <li class="roomType1">Some text for room 1</li>
</ul>
```

However if you really do want to display tabular data, you should not use an unordered list. Instead you should use nothing but a table, and then append rows (`<tr>`) as necessary. Just make sure you don't put the "All rooms" and "Create room" functional buttons into your table, as those are not tabular data.

A lot of this becomes important later when you are trying to advertise your hotel on search engines. Proper semantic layout is much easier for a search engine to dissect and advertise.

Comment: Tanks for replying, I simplified my list(`<ul><li>`), but in IE still cannot show correctly... or is the problem that IE is too slow to get the data, so the data cannot be shown(since the array in IE is empty)?
Is there anything to be care while use `<ul><li>` in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find that the httprequest in IE too slowly to get data when I want to change innerHTML of the list. It's my fault, I think I should ensure that the data is received before change UI.

Comment: You should probably look at using $.ajax() to make your calls, and put your list-building code inside the success() call which runs when ajax returns successfully.